# What tips are there for rewriting stream code so it doesn't use any units?

Tags: delphi-7, delphi

I am trying to port [some xor-encryption code](http://www.delphigeist.com/2009/09/text-encryption-with-xor.html) so it doesn't use any other units. I want to use just the commands, variables, and types that are supported natively by the compiler.

For example, here's some of the original code:

```
[...]
while (StreamIn.Position < StreamIn.Size) and
 ((StreamIn.Size -StreamIn.Position) >= szBuffer) do begin
 (* read 4 bytes at a time into a local integer variable *)
 StreamIn.ReadBuffer(buffer, szBuffer);
 (* the XOR encryption/decryption *)
 buffer := buffer xor theKey;
 buffer := buffer xor $E0F;
 (* write data to output stream *)
 StreamOut.WriteBuffer(buffer, szBuffer);
end;
[...]
```

This is my code:

```
function __NativeEncrypt (const Key, Source : String) : String;
// this function should not be used directly
// use EncryptText and DecryptText
const
 szBuffer = SizeOf(Integer); (* 4 bytes *)
 szByteBuffer = SizeOf(Byte); (* 1 byte *)
var
 byteBuffer,
 buffer,
 index,
 theKey: Integer;
 StreamIn  : String;
 StreamOut : String;
 i : Integer;
begin
 theKey := hashKey(Key);
 StreamIn := Source;
 StreamOut := '';
 for i := 1 to Length (StreamIn) do begin
  buffer := Integer(StreamIn[i]);
  buffer := buffer xor thekey;
  buffer := buffer xor $E0F;
  StreamOut := StreamOut + char(Buffer);
 end;
 result := StreamOut; // wrong results.
 // to continue...
end;
```

What tips are there for this task?

Comment: The code using streams is "native code". Native code means "in the language I'm using", and the first block of code is written in Delphi. You haven't indicated what problems you're having with your translation, other than a vague comment at the end about `// wrong results.`.

Comment: You're getting wrong results because the original code read and wrote integers, which are four bytes wide. Your new code reads and writes *characters*, which are either one or two bytes wide. Therefore, the "key" isn't being applied the same way, and so you get different results.

Comment: Benjamin; Surely you don't want to go back to using `Textfile`, and `Assign` ? That's not native, that's just OLD.  Oh, and crappy. Streams are the normal native modern way to program IO.

Comment: thanks rob. that was the issue first of all. And I thought native coding is coding without any other units. Just the commands/vars/types that are supported by the compiler, not units.

Comment: That would be a "standalone program, with zero used units", which would be pointless and would be more work, and probably more buggy, especially when the units you're using are standard VCL/RTL units.

Comment: Just to make sure you are aware of this: Delphi has a `TStringStream` class http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStringStream and a `TBytesStream` class http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Classes.TBytesStream that totally work 'in memory' (so don't depend on files).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason not to use library-provided units is as a learning exercise. I see no other reason to intentionally cripple yourself by refusing to use built-in features of your tools. Any answer to your general request for tips would rob you of the learning experience.

Most developers end up rewriting *something* from scratch at some point in their careers. However, unless it was imposed by a supervisor who suffers from extreme not-invested-here syndrome, it's nearly always a personal experience. You won't profit from their experience the same way you will from doing the work yourself. Doing it yourself will give you an understanding of what jobs the built-in tools do, and may give you some insight into why they're designed the way they are. Although you might be able to get those explanations from other people, unless you've actually tried to do it yourself, you won't really appreciate the explanations anyway.

My tip to you is to proceed with your project. I hope you find it interesting, and I wish you luck. If you eventually find yourself unable to make further progress, then identify the specific problem you're stuck on, and then ask others for help with that roadblock.